# sklearn: Pandas Dataframe vs Numpy ndarray - Which is more efficient to hold a [600k * 1k] data of different data types

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a classifier using sklearn. My underlying dataset is of the shape [600000, 1000]. While using sklearn classifiers, which is more efficient? Holding this dataset in a dataframe or an ndarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ndarray will be more efficient for the amount of information that you have provided, reason is obvious as pandas are designed for diverse purposes and performance isn't the most important consideration with respect to its flexibility and user friendliness, you can look at this example for [more details](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/numpy-vs-pandas-comparison.html)

Comment: hmmm, but `data of different data types`

Comment: A more exact answer will require us to take into consideration the kind of operations as well as the range of the size and the type of the data that we are going to undertake. Eg for strings larger than 10^7 rows pandas will do better for most  column operations.

Comment: I skew towards numpy as ultimately we will be feeding an array to the model. Please correct me if I am wrong @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

**Numpy will be faster for indexing and operations.**

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(600000,1000)
s = pd.DataFrame(a)

idx = range(1,100)

%timeit a[idx]
%timeit s.loc[idx]
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 62.9 µs per loop
>
> 1000 loops, best of 3: 582 µs per loop

---

**Bottom line:** `numpy` is faster